# DateTime SQL Problem

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I am trying to get my code to check to see if a number has already been entered for todays date. The reason for this is that the docketnumbers duplicate throughout the book, a bit like raffle tickets. I don't want the same number to be entered into the database more than once on the same day.

and now my code

```
string thisday = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

then the check

```
 public void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string thisday = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        errorProvider1.Clear();
        Data.docnum = txtDisplay.Text;
        if (txtDisplay.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtDisplay, "Enter Docket Number");
            return;
        }
        using (var db = new DocketsDataContext())
        {
             var docketCheck = from q in db.Dockets where q.Status== "Ca"  select q;   
             string message = "";
             foreach (var d in docketCheck)
             {
                 message += String.Format(" DocketNum {0} - Status {1} - TimeRaised {2} - Thisday {3}\r\n", d.DocketNum, d.Status, d.TimeRaised, thisday);
             }
             MessageBox.Show(message);


            var complete = from q in db.Dockets
                           where q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text && q.Status.Equals("CL") //&& q.TimeRaised.Contains(thisday)
                           select q;

            var cancelcheck = from q in db.Dockets
                              where q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text && q.Status.Equals("Ca") && q.TimeRaised.Equals(thisday)
                              select q;

            var docketcheck = from q in db.Dockets
                              where q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text && q.Status.Equals("O") //&& q.TimeRaised.Contains(thisday)
                              select q;

            var statuscheck = from q in db.Dockets
                              where q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text &&  q.Status.Equals("Ea") //&& q.TimeRaised.Contains(thisday)
                              select q;


            if (cancelcheck.Count() >= 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Match Found");
                txtDisplay.Clear();
                txtDisplay.ReadOnly = false;
                var cancel = new Cancel();
                cancel.ShowDialog(this);
            }

            else if (complete.Count() >= 1)
            {
                txtDisplay.Clear();
                txtDisplay.ReadOnly = false;
                var cat = new Docerror();
                cat.ShowDialog(this);
            }

            else if (statuscheck.Count() >= 1)
            {
                txtDisplay.Clear();
                txtDisplay.ReadOnly = false;
                var cat = new Category();
                cat.ShowDialog(this);
            }

            else if (docketcheck.Count() >= 1)
            {
                txtDisplay.Clear();
                txtDisplay.ReadOnly = false;
                var engs = new EngStart();
                engs.ShowDialog(this);
            }

            else
            {

                var sub = new machinesel();
                txtDisplay.Clear();
                sub.ShowDialog(this);
            }
        }

    }
```

when thisday matches today's date it should trigger the cancel feature but it is not; any ideas?

Jay

Comment: Are you storing the dates in the database as strings? If so, **Why**?. If you're storing them in the database as appropriate types (e.g. datetime), why are you working with strings at all? If you need a date without a time component, just use `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: Are you storing the date+time for the first entry of the day, or just the date(as in time==0:00)? If you store the real time then you will never get a match for .Today (where time = 0:00).

Comment: I am using linq2sql if that helps, the column in the table is datetime. 

And I need to store the time for calculating the span a docket took in minutes, but I only want to match the date on the checking part of the cancel check

Comment: @Jay - if `TimeRaised` in the database has a time component, it doesn't matter what you've done to the `thisDay` variable - except for those events which happened at midnight, `q.TimeRaised.Equals(thisday)` will not be true.

Comment: @Jay, by the way, LINQ2SQL supports `DateTime.Date` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx). So you can write a predicate in form `x=>x.TimeRaised.Date == lclDateVar`.

Comment: Can I not check to see is timeraised contains thisday? this has had me stumed for a few days now

Comment: According to [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/08/22/comparing-dates-in-linq-to-sql.aspx), you should be able to write your query as something like `q.TimeRaised.Date == DateTime.Day` and it should compare without time portions.

Comment: :-( stumbled this also dosnt work

Answer (score 1):

You are compering a `String` with a `DateTime`, that will never return true.
Try using the following:

```
var cancelCheck = 
  (from q in db.Dockets
   where 
    q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text && 
    q.Status.Equals("Ca") &&
    q.TimeRaised.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
  select q).Any();
```

Also, use `Any()` rather than  `Count() > 0`

Answer (score 0):

In your query, can you do something like this:

```
from q in db.Dockets
where q.DocketNum == txtDisplay.Text  
&& q.Status.Equals("CL")  
&& (q.TimeRaised - DateTime.Today).Hours >= 0  
&& !(q.TimeRaised > DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
select q;
```

Not sure if it's possible to add records with a future date, so I added the "*DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)*"
The logic is based on the TimeSpan class returned from comparing two dates:

```
  TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
  Console.WriteLine(ts.Days);
```

Which would give you the 365 days difference.